# How to handle Signal encryption protocol storage on web

Tags: reactjs, security, web-applications

I'm trying to create a messaging web-application with [whisper systems signal protocol](https://github.com/signalapp/libsignal-protocol-javascript) and I don't know where to store all the key and session state so that it will be durable and safe.

The only solution I can think of is that I store it on the server but how can I do that without giving the server full access to read the messages?

Comment: Improved English

Comment: You can't. Anyone with the session state can decrypt messages from the session.